# Change 2 fields automatically based on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I am using [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) and I have 2 select fields:

```
$('#field1').selectize();
$('#field2').selectize();
```

and I want to change automatically value of the second, when the first field has changed (or selected); and vice versa, change value of first when value of second has changed (or selected).

I was using [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function, like this:

```
$("#field1").change(function () {
    var d = 'value-field2'
    var $select_field2 = $("#id_field2").selectize();
    var selectize_field2 = $select_field2[0].selectize;
    selectize_field2.setValue(d);
  });

  $("#field2").change(function () {
      var d = 'value-field1'
      var $select_field1 = $("#id_field1").selectize();
      var selectize_field1 = $select_field1[0].selectize;
      selectize_field1.setValue(d);
  });
  });
```

But here I go in an infinite call of these 2 functions, calling each other, because they change each other.
I tried using `mouseover()` or `click()` instead of `change()` but didn't succed to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or post the minimum code required to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I updated the code example. Does this help?

Comment: Please add the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of variable to identify when the JavaScript is changing the value instead of the user. You could use something like this:

```js
var programmaticallyChanging = false;

$("#field1").change(function() {
    if (!programmaticallyChanging) {
        var d = 'value-field2'
        var $select_field2 = $("#id_field2").selectize();
        var selectize_field2 = $select_field2[0].selectize;
        programmaticallyChanging = true;
        selectize_field2.setValue(d);
        programmaticallyChanging = false;
    }
});

$("#field2").change(function() {
    if (!programmaticallyChanging) {
        var d = 'value-field1'
        var $select_field1 = $("#id_field1").selectize();
        var selectize_field1 = $select_field1[0].selectize;
        programmaticallyChanging = true;
        selectize_field1.setValue(d);
        programmaticallyChanging = false
    }
});
```

If possible, put the var programmaticallyChanging = false; into some function so that it's not exposed on the window.

Comment: It worked. Good point to identify when JS is changing the value.